# Grouping and sum of columns and eliminate duplicates in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, grouping

I have a data frame like below in `pyspark`

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
('14_100_00','A',25,0),
('14_100_00','A',0,24),
('15_100_00','A',20,1),
('150_100','C',21,0),
('16','A',0,20),
('16','A',20,0)],("rust", "name", "value_1","value_2" ))

df.show()
+---------+----+-------+-------+
|     rust|name|value_1|value_2|
+---------+----+-------+-------+
|14_100_00|   A|     25|      0|
|14_100_00|   A|      0|     24|
|15_100_00|   A|     20|      1|
|  150_100|   C|     21|      0|
|       16|   A|      0|     20|
|       16|   A|     20|      0|
+---------+----+-------+-------+
```

I am trying to update the `value_1` and `value_2` columns based on below conditions

1. when `rust` and `name` columns are same then sum of `value_1` as `value_1` for that group
2. when `rust` and `name` columns are same then sum of `value_2` as `value_2` for that group

Expected result:

```
+---------+----+-------+-------+
|     rust|name|value_1|value_2|
+---------+----+-------+-------+
|14_100_00|   A|     25|     24|
|15_100_00|   A|     20|      1|
|  150_100|   C|     21|      0|
|       16|   A|     20|     20|
+---------+----+-------+-------+
```

I have tried this:

```
df1 = df.withColumn("VALUE_1", f.sum("VALUE_1").over(Window.partitionBy("rust", "name"))).withColumn("VALUE_2", f.sum("VALUE_2").over(Window.partitionBy("rust", "name")))
df1.show()
+---------+----+-------+-------+
|     rust|name|VALUE_1|VALUE_2|
+---------+----+-------+-------+
|  150_100|   C|     21|      0|
|       16|   A|     20|     20|
|       16|   A|     20|     20|
|14_100_00|   A|     25|     24|
|14_100_00|   A|     25|     24|
|15_100_00|   A|     20|      1|
+---------+----+-------+-------+
```

Is there a better way to achieve this without having duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupBy` instead of window functions:

```py
df1 = df.groupBy("rust", "name").agg(
    F.sum("value_1").alias("value_1"),
    F.sum("value_2").alias("value_2"),
)
df1.show()
#+---------+----+-------+-------+
#|     rust|name|value_1|value_2|
#+---------+----+-------+-------+
#|14_100_00|   A|     25|     24|
#|15_100_00|   A|     20|      1|
#|  150_100|   C|     21|      0|
#|       16|   A|     20|     20|
#+---------+----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: here in the example I have only `4` columns. I want to select columns other than `rust, name` how can I do that using `groupBy`

Comment: Insert them all in the `groupBy` clause, if you want to group on them.